# Three.js and Tween.js chain of animations not cycling

Tags: javascript, three.js, tween.js

I am attempting to translate a Three.js cube using the Tween.js library.

By creating two **tween** objects I can move the cube back and forth:

```
var start_position = { x : 0.0 , y: 0.0 };
var target = { x : 3.0, y: 0.0 };

var tween_to = new TWEEN.Tween(start_position)
            .to(target, 2000);



var start_position2 = { x : 3.0 , y: 0.0 };
var target2 = { x : 0.0, y: 0.0 };

var tween_fro = new TWEEN.Tween(start_position2)
            .to(target2, 1000);



tween_to.onUpdate(onUpdate);
tween_fro.onUpdate(onUpdate);

function onUpdate()
{
  cube.position.x = this.x;
  cube.position.y = this.y;
};

tween_to.chain(tween_fro);

tween_to.start();
```

Then in my animation loop I have:

```
TWEEN.update();
```

This works **fine**.  However if I complete the cycle by referencing the first tween from the second for example:

```
tween_to.chain(tween_fro);
tween_fro.chain(tween_to);
```

The animation jumps between extremes without any interpolation, it just appears at each position (after the first cycle is complete).

I assume I am misusing the library somehow, but following guides online I don't see how this method differs from the official Tween.js examples.

Comment: Conjecture: your problem may be your use of `this.x`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can chain Tweens using this pattern:

```
function onUpdate() {

    cube.position.x = position.x;
    cube.position.y = position.y;

};

var position = { x : 0.0 , y: 0.0 };

var tween_to = new TWEEN.Tween( position )
    .to( { x : 10.0, y: 0.0 }, 2000 )
    .onUpdate( onUpdate );

var tween_fro = new TWEEN.Tween( position )
    .to( { x : 0.0, y: 0.0 }, 1000 )
    .onUpdate( onUpdate );

tween_to.chain( tween_fro );
tween_fro.chain( tween_to );

tween_to.start();

...

TWEEN.update();
```

Or, more simply, like so:

```
var tween_to = new TWEEN.Tween( cube.position )
    .to( { x : 10.0, y: 0.0 }, 2000 );

var tween_fro = new TWEEN.Tween( cube.position )
    .to( { x : 0.0, y: 0.0 }, 1000 );

tween_to.chain( tween_fro );
tween_fro.chain( tween_to );

tween_to.start();

...

TWEEN.update();
```